# mysql query data group

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql table like that

[image]
and i need to run a query which will output the following result

[image]

what will be mysql query for that?any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT data, count(*) 
FROM   your_table 
GROUP BY 
       data
```